# Whitelisting URL Schemes workaround

Tags: ios, security, url-scheme, privacy, info.plist

iOS 9 brings new security and privacy measures. One such measure is to prevent the abuse of canOpenURL to discover the Apps a user has installed.

Apple restricts the querying of URL schemes. If you build and link against the iOS 9+ SDK you need to **whitelist the schemes** your app will query.

I have a case when the list of apps which I will open from my application is unknown at the development time.

How do you think, is there any **workaround** with it?

Comment: The whitelist is set in the `info.plist` which is main bundle and cannot be edit at run time. This is because the main bundle is readonly. You will have to supply the whitelist before submitting your app.

Comment: Yes, and at the same time, there are apps(e.g. Launch Center Pro) which have found the solution with calling other apps without knowing them exactly at the development time. I will use it with **Enterprise license** (outside Appstore distribution)

Comment: Well you should ask them then. Since it is not possible with the default SDK. You might be able to use some private API, but I can't help you with this.

Answer (score 3):

As per this [Article](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl/), You do not need to have a scheme listed in Info.plist to be able to open it with openURL. This mechanism only applies to canOpenURL and not openURL.

Comment: It`s for ForMedia and InWebContent

Comment: By configuring this key’s value in your app’s Info.plist file, you can customize the security of your network connections in a variety of ways. You can:

Allow insecure communication with particular servers
Allow insecure loads for web views or for media, while maintaining ATS protections elsewhere in your app
Enable new security features such as Certificate Transparency https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

Comment: @VityaShurapov I have updated the answer, please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Link doesn't  work And I need this canOpenURL method :)

Comment: @VityaShurapov Yes, there was a mistake. I have updated the link. Thank you.